# Experience of including checksum in all emails

Tags: checksum

I would be interested to hear any advice or experience of including a checksum link in all emails sent to our various newsletter lists.
We're interested in doing this because we have quite a variety of email lists on different topics. This means an opt-out link (which we obviously include as well) is quite a blunt tool for controlling what sort of content people receive. We would rather regularly offer them the option of updating their preferences if they're not getting the email newsletters they want from us.
Does anyone include a regular email checksum link in their emails? Have you run into any problems doing so?

Answer (score 1):

I've run checksum on all emails to over 160K recipients without issue. Just make a profile or respective CMS form (Drupal webform / Caldera Form) that allows them to select the public email groups you want them to opt into or out of.

I like to extend the checksum expiration to say 30 days.

Comment: good point re checksum life - it often gets overlooked